# Using multiple SESSION variables on a single page not working

Tags: php, session-variables

On my site, the login.php page (if successful login) will redirect to index.php and will start a session and 2 SESSION variables.

One of the variables started is a success message:

```
$_SESSION["message"] = "Login successful!";
```

the second is the user session variable:

```
$_SESSION["authenticatedUserEmail"] = $email;
```

the problem is that if I check the variables individually and then try and use them on the index.php page, only the first one that is checked will work.

This following snippet will show the `$form_message` but it will not show the `$_SESSION["authenticatedUserEmail"]`:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["message"])) {
    $form_message = $_SESSION["message"];
    session_unset($_SESSION["message"]);
    echo $form_message;
} else {
    $form_message = "";
}


if (isset($_SESSION["authenticatedUserEmail"])) {

    echo $_SESSION["authenticatedUserEmail"];

}
```

It does work when I only use one `if(isset($_SESSION` statement but I don't want to always include both inside the same statement.

I've done an error check:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

but no errors appear.

Can anyone please suggest why this may not be working or if I am missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

session_unset function free all session variable. this is why when you are using session_unset, next session variable is not founded. read the manual please.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php

to achieve what you want you can use unset function

```
unset($_SESSION["message"]);
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `session_unset` is the problem, you should be simply using `unset`.

`session_unset` unsets the whole `$_SESSION` array.